# How to perform mass delete on Laravel from Vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a massive delete function for a website to delete a list of products at the same time. I insert the data through an excel.

Controller function

```php
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $products = $request->all();

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $dbProduct = $this->getProduct($product['SKU']);
            Log::error($dbProduct);
            $dbProduct->delete();
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error eliminando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }
}

private function getProduct($sku)
{
    $product = Product::where('sku', $sku)->first();
    return $product;
}
```

I"m not sure how to do the @click method on the vue part, right now i have this, but this is used to upload on other page, not sure what to change to make it delete instead. It's receiving an array that has been separated into groups of 50, thats the (data, index).

```
sendData(data, index) {
  this.loading = true;
  this.error = {};
  this.$http.post(this.baseUrl, data, this.params).then(
    () => {
      this.successAction();
      this.statuses[index] = 1;
      this.errorDis = false;
    },
    res => {
      this.showErrors(res);
      this.statuses[index] = 2;
      this.errorDis = true;
    }
  );
}
```

Currently i get a success status but it's not deleting the products

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you can delete all the products with one query instead of `$products->count() * 2` queries, something like that:

```php
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    //ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); no need IMHO
    $products = collect($request->all());
    $skus = $products->pluck('SKU');

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        Product::whereIn('sku', $skus)->delete();
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error eliminando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }
    // it's better to return something here
    return response('Finished!', 200);
}
```

**Update:** 
As pointed by @ceejayoz the function above bypass the *individual eloquent events* `deleting` and `deleted`, in case you need them, or you need the single `Product` model, here is a *less stripped* version that executes `$products->count() + 1` queries:

```php
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    //ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); probably unneeded
    $skus = collect( $request->all() )->pluck('SKU');
    $products = Product::whereIn('sku', $skus)->get();
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            Log::error($product);
            $product->delete();
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error eliminando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }
    // it's better to return something here
    return response('Finished!', 200);
}
```

Comment: One note: Doing it this way bypasses Eloquent events on the individual models, IIRC. Not a big deal for most apps, but something to be aware of if you rely on them.

Comment: Thank for the point @ceejayoz, probably I simplyfied too much the original logic, I'll add a more featured version of the controller.

Comment: @dparoli i tried this but still doesn't delete, is the code on my vue component right? i'm getting a success status but it doesn't delete anything?

Comment: Maybe you are not sending the correct data, you should debug the vue request data by logging it or echoing. But I am not an expert of vuejs, I can help only on the backend side.

Comment: @dparoli the only data i'm sending is an array of the products unique sku

Comment: Maybe or maybe not, you should debug your data and the url you're sending, with the code posted I cannot guess anymore sorry, the controller function works but you have to send the correct data to correct url to work.